# Maple: How to define new elements of a matrix?

Tags: matrix, maple

In Maple, I have a matrix N and its elements N[i,j], If I modify the elements of this matrix as follows for example

```
>for j from 1 to 4 do
>print(F[i,j]=(diff(N[i,j],x)));
>od;od;
```

where the matrix elements are functions of x.

I've wanted to define new matrix elements

```
>BA[i,j]:=(diff(N[i,j],x)));
```

but I can't do this with Maple, through the above command. Can someone help me ?

Comment: Got it ! for i from 1 to 4 do
for j from 1 to 4 do
BA[i,j]:=diff(N[i,j],v);
od;od;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better than using a loop is simply **BA:= diff~(N,x)**. The **~** can be appended to any operator to mean "apply the operator to each member of the container and return a new container containing the modified members."

Also, be careful about using **print**. Its only purpose is to print stuff on the screen from the middle (not the end) of a computation. It can't be used to change any stored values. Good programs use **print** very sparingly, if at all. The end result of a computation is displayed automatically, without needing a print command.

Comment: Thank you very much ! You helped me a lot.